# What does classname functionname(const classname & objectname) means?

Tags: c++, class, object, constants, pass-by-reference

I have an assigment where we should do resistor calculations (series and parallel) using the following class :

```cpp
class R1 {

protected:
   double R , cost_in_euro ;
      string unit ;
public :

   R1(double R , const string & unit , double cost_in_euro);
   R1(double R , double cost_in_euro);
   R1(double R);
   R1(const R1 & R);


   R1 serie(const R1 & R1);
   R1 parallel(const R1 & R1);



};
```

My question is regarding the functions serie and parallel . How am i supposed to add 2 resistors using a function that only takes one single object as an argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need one parameter because the class contains the information for one R, and the parameter contains the information for the other R.

```
    class R1 {
        protected:
        double R , cost_in_euro ;
            string unit ;
        public :

        R1(double R , const string & unit , double cost_in_euro);
        R1(double R , double cost_in_euro);
        R1(double R);
        R1(const R1 & R);


        R1 serie(const R1 & other)
        {
            double total = other.R + R;
            return R1(total);
        }

        R1 parallel(const R1 & other)
        {
            double r1 = other.R;
            double r2 = R;
            double total = (r1*r2)/(r1 + r2);

            return R1(total);
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

> How am i supposed to add 2 resistors using a function that only takes
>   one single object as an argument?

Example of how 2 instances of your class (a and b) might work together:

```
// using 'lists' require -std=c++17 or newer

#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::endl;  // c++17

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw, std::setfill; // c++17

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <sstream>
using std::stringstream;


class R1
{
protected:
   double m_R,  m_cost;
   string m_unit;

public :
   R1(double R , const string & unit , double cost_in_euro);
   R1(double R , double cost_in_euro);

   R1(double R)  // <<<<<<<<< dummy implmentation
      : m_R (R)
      , m_cost (9.9)
      , m_unit ("a unit")
      {
         cout << "\n  ctor R1(double) " << show() << endl;
      }

   R1(const R1 & R);

   R1 serie(const R1&  r2)  // <<<<<<<<<< with diag cout
      {
         cout << "\n  serie " << show() << "\n        "
              << r2.show() << endl;
         return (R1(r2.m_R + m_R));
      }

   R1 parallel(const R1& r2) // <<<<<<<<<< with diag cout
      {
         cout << "\n  parallel " << show() << "\n           "
              << r2.show() << endl;
         return ((r2.m_R * m_R) / (r2.m_R + m_R));
      }

   string show() const
      {
         stringstream ss;
         ss << "  [m_R: " << m_R << "  m_cost: " << m_cost
            << "  '" << m_unit << "']";
         return ss.str();
      }
};


class F805_t 
{
public:
   int operator()()
      {
         R1 a(2.0);

         R1 b(3.0);

         a.serie(b);     // <<<<<<<<< instance a using b

         b.parallel(a);  // <<<<<<<<< instance b using a

         return 0;
   }

}; // class F805_t


int main(int , char**) { return F805_t()(); }
```